# Which database should I use for my Node.js app that can operate with iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a Node.js application with MongoDB as database. I also want to develop an iOS and Android app for my Node.js application. Which database should I use for my Node.js app that can operate with iOS and Android?

Kind regards,

Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons of having REST API, which probably you develop using Node.js, is to provide a high level abstraction on top of any implementation(s), which can be based on any database. So the database of your choice should be the one which fits your business requirements and data insertion and access patterns. Or just start with the one which you know, or is simple enough to set up and use for beginners. Conclusion, if you have no reasons to change MongoDB to something different, you can use it further.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer! I think I can go along with my app.